# build number not divisible by given number

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I am curious if I have following proof correct.
Given number $N$ I would like to build a number not divisible by $N$.

1. Let's take $Np$, where p is some integer.
2. Now, take $Q= Np + d$ where $0<d<N$.

*$Q$ is not divisible by $N$.*

Proof: Assume contrary that $Q$ is divisible by $N$. it means $Q = Nt$.
We have:

$$Nt = Np + d$$

$$N (t-p) = d$$

Let's divide both sides on $N$.
We have:

$$t-p = d/N$$

but on the left side is integer, and it can't equal the right side which is fraction, unless $N$ divides $d$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Well, $N$ could be $1$, but otherwise just take $N+1$. The GCD between $N$ and $N+1$ is just $1$...

Comment: @Dair So for proof to work I need to add condition N!=1?

Comment: I don't understand your construction.  Let, say, $N=12$ and $p=24$, $d=12$.  Then $d<p$ surely but $N\times p+d$ is divisible by $N$.

Comment: @lulu I am really sorry I messed conditions for d, please check

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct, just take $d=0,$ Then $Q$ is always divisible by $N.$ Now if $d>0,$ then it's still not correct, as we can take $p>N$ as the integers are unbounded, and then set $d=N.$ It is correct if $1\leq d<N,$ but this forces us to choose $N\not=1.$ So if $N>1,$ and $1<d<N,$ then for any integer $p$ it follows that $Np+d$ is not divisible by $N.$

Comment: I am sorry I messed conditions for d, please check again the question

Comment: @gdan, yes now it is correct. This is actually closed connected to modular arithmetic. I'd suggest reading about it. You can show an integer is divisible by $N$ if and only if its remainder is, so the trick here is just build an integer where the remainder is no divisible by $N.$

Comment: ok thanks. and i know sometimes we can't divide both sides of equality on number, that is true when the number can be `0` right?

Comment: @gdan, yes we must assume $N\not=0.$ Actually in the case where $N=0$ we could say that by convention $0$ doesn't divide any number other than 0, hence we can just take any number other than $0$ to work. So we might as well only consider $N\not=0.$ Again though we need $N\not=1,$ and for similar reasons we need $N\not=-1.$ So we might as well just assume $N>1$ as $N$ divides any number $-N$ does, and vice versa.